# How to push new object in array with variables as key and value, also im not sure that i do it right with methode replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        dataValidation = "min:7 max:20 alphanumeric required";
        var params = [];
        dataValidation.replace(/([^\s]+).?/g, function(a, b){
             var split = b.split(':');
             if (split[1])
                params.push([split[0]] = split[1]);
             else
                params.push([split[0]] = true);
              return
            });
```

My code, i want to create array of objects, with keys and values, split[0] and split[1], but the result for this is something like that

> ["7", "20", true, true]

instead of

> [{min:7}, {max:20}...].

Also im not sure that creating function inside replace is best way to do it.

Comment: You are pushing variable, push() is array function. If you use like that it just pushes, no check no object nothing. You need to use push({"key":"value"}). So you need to use JSON.

Comment: I need to use variable as key to perform a method later with them. Also i dont see how json can solve this, its typically javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by modifyin code

```
        dataValidation.replace(/([^\s]+).?/g, function(a, b){
            var split = b.split(':');
            var obj = {};
            if (split[1])
                obj[split[0]] = split[1];
            else
                obj[split[0]] = true;
            params.push(obj);
            return
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

// Alternative, since regexp is greedy

```
var output = [], tmp;
['foo:bar','bar:baz'].forEach(function(el, idx, arr) {
  tmp = {};
  tmp[el.substr(0,el.indexOf(':'))] = el.substr(el.indexOf(':')+1);
  output.push(tmp);
});
console.log(output);
//> [{bar:"baz"},{foo:"bar"}]
```

Comment: Add appropriate condition to validate the format of each item to parse.